# Multiple of the similar "Select Option" ID , Dynamic Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, selectize.js

[image]

1) I need to find a way to have multiple of id="select-repo" because every single "add another item" is the same. "Add Another Item" is suppose to add another row of html with that id="select-repo" for now it's just a empty textbox.

Generate Functions on the go? Dynamic Functions? I can easily loop the Select box but not the "$('#select-repo').selectize({" function i believe.

2) After number 1 is solved, I need to find a way to know which row of data to update after an option has been selected.

3) Is this easier to get done with VUE.JS, since i'm using laravel , integration should be easier with **Vue.JS**

What is your advice, I was told to use stuff like ReactJS / styled components? is there anyway to not switch framework to just get this done?

Please Advice.

**HTML Code**

```
<td><select id="select-repo" class="repositories"></select></td>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>
                //<select id="select-repo"></select>
                $('#select-repo').selectize({
                    valueField: 'url',
                    labelField: 'name',
                    searchField: 'name',
                    options: [],
                    create: false,
                    render: {
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                            return '<div>' +
                                '<span class="title">' +
                                    '<span class="name"><i class="icon ' + (item.fork ? 'fork' : 'source') + '"></i>' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' +
                                    '<span class="by">' + escape(item.username) + '</span>' +
                                '</span>' +
                                '<span class="description">' + escape(item.description) + '</span>' +
                                '<ul class="meta">' +
                                    (item.language ? '<li class="language">' + escape(item.language) + '</li>' : '') +
                                    '<li class="watchers"><span>' + escape(item.watchers) + '</span> watchers</li>' +
                                    '<li class="forks"><span>' + escape(item.forks) + '</span> forks</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    score: function(search) {
                        var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
                        return function(item) {
                            return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
                        };
                    },
                    load: function(query, callback) {
                        if (!query.length) return callback();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/' + encodeURIComponent(query),
                            type: 'GET',
                            error: function() {
                                callback();
                            },
                            success: function(res) {
                                callback(res.repositories.slice(0, 10));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    onChange: function(value) {
               alert(value);
          }
                });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since id can not be the same, you can define a **global variable** like index to memo the count as part of id;

Like to dynamically add select with id "select-repo"+index; e.g. select-repo1, select-repo999

Here's an example:

```
var index = 1;

function addSelect(){
    $('#somewhere').append('<select id="select-repo'+index+'">');
    $('select-rep'+index).selectize(){
        ....
    };
    index++;
}
```

And you can easily get the select index by parse Id string.

Comment: $('#select-repo').selectize({ << how do i deal with this at the function level. Generate functions on the go?

Comment: Yes! if you do the things above, you should make the $('#select-repo').selectize as general as you can.